# How to call print function in new window after page is loaded?

Tags: angularjs

Ok i have this button :

and i have this function for confirm ticket:

```
   $scope.ConfirmTicketPayOut = function (ticketPin, username)
    {
        $scope.ticketPin = ticketPin;
        localStorage.setItem("ticketPin", ticketPin);
        accountDataProviderService.confirmTicketPayOut(ticketPin, username)
        .then(function (response) {

            $scope.confirmTicketPayOut = response;
            if ($scope.confirmTicketPayOut.Result == true)
            {
                    var w = $window.open('/account/ticketprint');
                    angular.element(w).bind('load', function () {
                        w.print();
                    });
            }   
        });
    }
```

I have problem because when user click on button i need to open new window with data and to call print option. In this case i get print option and new window is open but the page is blank so my conclusion is that page is loaded after print option is appeared. I need to load page and show print option at same time, but without `$timeout`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try using angular event `viewContentLoaded`. call your method after this event is fired.

Example

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {

    // Your method call

}
```

Comment: in your print controller . where you call print function

Comment: like this?   $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
                    var w = $window.open('/account/ticketprint');
                    angular.element(w).bind('load', function () {
                        w.print();
                    });

                   
                });